# WebApp in HTML Upload in iOS 6.1.3 wrong fakepath

Tags: html, ios, upload, mobile-safari, iphone-web-app

I have a problem with the new fakepath feature in iOS. All files got renamed to the path "C:\fakepath\image.jpg".

In previous iOS 6 versions everything worked fine, files had their original name “…/IMG_...”, but one of the last updates seems to break something by introducing this stricter fakepath. I think the problem is following, could someone please confirm?:
Uploading .jpgs does still work. Uploading .pngs doesn't. If I do upload a .png file from camera roll (e.g. a screenshot), the filepath is replaced by "C:\fakepath\image.jpg" and is just renamed to an .jpg file (content seems to stay png). I think, the correct fakepath in this case would be "C:\fakepath\image.png". Here starts the trouble.

Is this a bug in mobile Safari? Or is my HTML code buggy (using some GWT magic). Tried it on my device with pure HTML, too - same issue. Is my phone "misconfigured"?
I would be happy if somebody could confirm this bug before I implement some server-side magic as workaround. Could not find anything on the internet.

Greets and Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The configuration of mobile safari is not usually a problem since apple doesn't give you a lot of options to actually change the configuration of safari on the mobile device. It could be a buggy html code. Try using emulators of different mobile safari versions. If the problem is only in one version of safari, try looking at the documentation of the updated version and see if they changed something like how the safari interprets certain tags in html5, so try to go over most of it and look into your code. If still nothing, you can always use some scripting to handle that certain error. It might be a lengthy process. So, good luck.